# .Net Process WaitForExit returning error code 2

Tags: c#, .net, process

I have a .NET application that returns exit code 2, "Process has exited, so the requested information is not available", when getting the exit code of an external process. Is it that the jar process completing before WaitForExit has a chance to check?

The actual process completes successfully. The rest of my code is dependent on having an exit code of 0;

```
Process p = new Process();

p.StartInfo.Filename = "cmd";
p.StartInfo.Arguments=@"/c java -jar app.jar";
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
code = p.ExitCode;
```

Comment: Well, this means that the process exits with exit code 2, although it "completes" successfully. What exit code does the process return if you start it from the command line using the very same command?

Comment: By the way, do you really need to start java via cmd? Why not launch java.exe directly?

Comment: Ahh, yes you are correct, when I run the jar from command line it exits with 2. Also, I was having some trouble before running java.exe directly, I havent had time to investigate why.

Comment: One issue with launching java directly might be because it fails to locate java.exe, but it would be the same with launching it via cmd, I guess.

Comment: Yes I think finding java.exe was the issue, and I didn't want to change any environment variables or anything. Just want the application to run with as little changes to the sever environment as possible. Would you happen to know of any techniques to investigate why the jar is returning 2?

Comment: whomp whomp... I just checked the documentation for the external process. An exit code of 2 is expected. Thought 0 the norm... Thanks for your help!